# XML binding solution in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, binding, oxm

Are there any proper xml binding(mapping) solutions (OXM) in .net? What I need is to generate model classes from arbitrary xml. As for now I can't find anything like JaXB 1/2, JiBX, Castor XML, XMLBeans in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for...but you can take a look at xsd.exe. It can do some pretty neat stuff.

Comment: Yeah, this could be an option. At least it would generate model classes from provided xsd document.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx). I think this might be just the thing you need. We used it for some ORM in previous projects but it's pretty versatile.

Comment: Nope, we need library with well defined interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [here](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm) a nice overview of xml binding solutions

[XMLObjects](http://www.coderazzi.net/csharp/xmlobjects/index.html) library seems suitable

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate schemaless data binding approach (below is the URL)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/schemaless_binding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is also an schemaless approach to data binding, here is a link to an introductory article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/schemaless_binding.aspx